# adding up total occurrences then inserting them into a "total" column

Tags: mysql

I have a single table called "builds" I need to be able to run a SQL query every so often that reads a column "machine type" counts up the total occurrences of "type1","type2", and "type3" then updates the columns "totalType1", "totalType2", and "totalType3" with the operate totals.

```
UPDATE builds 
SET totalType1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE MACHINE_TYPE = 'type1'),
 totalType2 = (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE MACHINE_TYPE = 'type2'),
 totalType3 = (SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE MACHINE_TYPE = 'type3')
```

this is what i have, it runs, but does not do what i want, hopefully you can get a better understanding of the question.

Comment: Think you should really be storing the "total_type" in the same table?  If you do, you will have total_type populated for every machine in your table.  Best bet would be to create a separate table that stores the total types.

Comment: Think you shouldn't be storing totaltype at all